# Overriding the same Back office views in multiples modules

Tags: php, symfony, prestashop-1.7

My feature is related to the concept of **[Overriding Back office views](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/templating/admin-views/)**

Like the documentation say, to override an admin template in a module, we need to :

- Found the right template (using debug toolbar)
- Create the same path (modules/mod_name/view/PrestaShop/.../...) and add the view
- Refer to the original template using the **extends** annotation.
- Refer to an existing block using **block** annotation.

**Basic Hello World example:**

```
// Refer to the original template this the extends annotation.
{% extends 'PrestaShopBundle:Admin/Product/CatalogPage:catalog.html.twig' %}

//Refer to an existing block using block annotation.
{% block product_catalog_filters %}
  Hello world!
{% endblock %}
```

So ok, overriding a back office views  work like a charm.

But let's imagine this use case:

- We have a **module A**, that overrides a back office view and uses a
  block (**ex: block product_catalog_filters**).
- We want to install a    new **module B**, that overrides the same
  back office view and the    same block (**ex: block
  product_catalog_filters**).

Here we have a problem, the last module installed (**Module B**) is going to override the back office view. But all override from the **Module A** are going to be lost.

I have found a solution. But for me, it's not a good practice.

We can add a custom block in the desired Prestashop back office view. ( **So we need to write code in a Prestashop core file**).

If we doing this, our module can override the back office view and call our custom block.

With this custom block, we are sure that just our module is going to override the view and avoid override conflict with potential other modules

Do you know of any other way to do the override without having to write code in a Prestashop core file?

Comment: There's no other way :(